# javascript examples display content boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to locate javascript code that, when I rollover an image, will make a box appear below the image and expand down (much like how a movie screen in a theater would roll from the ceiling to the floor). In that box, content would also appear, that I have previously added, that describes the image above. Already existing underneath the image I have a div with content in it...I would also like this div to be pushed down as the box described above expands down.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

C*

Forgot the code that I am using...so what is happening here is that I have a picture, and below it, a small box, that when I rollover that small box it changes color. So, I want to add, when I scroll over that small box, not only does it still change color, but the new vertical expanding box appears below it. I have javascript in a *.js file that handles the already existing rollover effect but it's quite long and I wasn't sure if I should add that (it was create by Dreamweaver when I created a rollover image).

```
<div class="images">

<figure class="images">
<img src="../images/Flower2.jpg" width="300" height="199" alt="Life">
</figure>

<figcaption class="content"><a class="typeB" href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image3','','../graphics/life2.jpg',4)"><img src="../graphics/life1.jpg" width="300" height="25" id="Image3" /></a>
</figcaption>

</div>
```

Comment: We can't help you "locate" this code, but we can help you fix whatever you already have already written.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give much information in your question about your current setup, but assuming that you have your **HTML** set out something like this:

```
<div>
    <img id="tux" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/Crystal_128_penguin.png" />
    <div id="tux_desc" class="imgDesc" style="display: none">
        <p>A cute penguin!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p>This text is part of the normal document flow</p>
</div>
```

Then you can use the following **JavaScript** (which makes use of jQuery):

```
$('#tux').hover(
    function() {
        $('#tux_desc').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
        $('#tux_desc').slideUp();
    });
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/wbAxm/1

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! :) I went back and added the code that I am using. Looking at what you had posted and what I had posted does my request make sense?...or is it just too messy to throw it all into one rollover effect?...essentially, I am attempting to create a rollover that produces a number of things.

Comment: @user1912669, it's probably not too messy, but Dreamweaver will probably make it that way. I haven't used Dreamweaver in a long time but from my experience it does seem to produce a lot of bloat. What you want can probably be implemented by some well structured HTML and some custom JavaScript/jQuery code. (However, I can't quite tell from your question exactly what you want to change colour, and what you want to slide down etc.)

Answer (score 1):

something like this ought to to do it as long as the div to expand is directly after the image in the mark-up:

```
$(".class_for_images").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    var content = $(this).next();

    if (content.is(":visible")) {
        content.slideUp();
    } else {
        content.slideDown();
    }
});
```

If you want more than this, or it doesn't work, you'll need to post some code so that we can provide more detailed answers...

Comment: `toggleSlide` would be cleaner there :)